# Recursive Async function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, asynchronous, recursion

I have a question about a problem I am bumping into. I am using **AngularJS** as my framework and do not have access to **jQuery** nor **Lodash**.

**The problem**

I have a function called "refresh". That function makes an async call via angular $http to get new data from the server. The server only gives 25 new updates to me from the date I specify. So to get all the new messages I need to call the server (and update the "updateDate" everytime I get data) until it tells me that it has no more messages (empty array).

**Code example**

```
$scope.refresh = function () {
    var date = new Date();

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://path.to.my.server',
        timeout: 6000
    }).then(function (success) {  
        date = success.date[0].date; //0 is always the newest message                     
        callback(success.data);       
        //Do some stuff with the data
    }, function (error) {
        console.error("Could not retrieve new messages: \n", error.data);
        errcallback(error);
    });
```

}

---

**What I have tried**

I have tried to get set the request in a separate function and make calls to it like you would do with a normal a-sync function.

I have also tried a while loop and setting a boolean when I am done with collecting. The only problem is that a while loop doesn't wait for the call to end (otherwise it wouldn't be async) and makes quite an impressive loop (not yet infinite, but enough to crash my program).

I was thinking about a for loop, but I do not know how much iterations I should make. It could be 1 but also could also be 5 or more.

*I know how recursive functions work, but I do not know how I should use an async recursive function. Any advice or solutions are welcome. (I won't have to be recursive if anyone knows an other solution)*

Comment: how did you send the date to the webservice ?

Comment: So you have already tried executing`$scope.refresh()` in your `.then()` callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing particularly special about making async functions recursive, you just don't have to worry about running out of stack.

Just isolate your ajax call into a function, and have that function call itself until it has a complete picture of the data:

```
$scope.refresh = function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var results = [];

    gather();

    function gather() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://path.to.my.server',
            timeout: 6000
            // presumably using `date` here?
        }).then(function(success) {
            // This seems to assume you'll always have at least
            // one row, which doesn't seem to match with your description
            date = success.data[0].date; //0 is always the newest message                     
            if (thereAreNewResults) {
                results.push.apply(results, success.data);
                gather();
            } else {
                // We're done
                callback(results);       
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("Could not retrieve new messages: \n", error.data);
            errcallback(error);
        });
    }
};
```

That's not meant to be full-formed and perfect, but it should send you in the right direction.

Note my `if (thereAreNewResults)`. I would have thought that would be `if (success.data.length)` but the code in your question seemed to suggest there'd always be at least one row, so adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I didn't know that you could create a function within a function.

Answer (score 0):

I will make a recursive function who get the data :

```
$scope.refresh = function () {

    $scope.allDatas = [];

    var getData = function(date){   
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://path.to.my.server'+/ date , // should format date her
            timeout: 6000
        }).then(function (success) {  
            date = success.date[0].date; //0 is always the newest message                
            //Do some stuff with the data; all the datas will be available in $scope.allDatas
            $scope.allDatas = $scope.allDatas.concat(success.data);     
            // call again ? 
            if( /* decide when you stop getting data */ ){
                getData(date);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("Could not retrieve new messages: \n", error.data);
            errcallback(error);
        });
    }
    var date = new Date();
    // launch the function
    getData(date);  
}
```